# How to create two objects with one action in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm making an inventory system, and I want to be able to track every CRUD operation in my application so I made another table in my DB as `TrackHistory`. The idea is when an object (laptop for an example) is created, another object is created as `TrackHistory`.

In the `TrackHistory` object we are adding the user that changed it, what method he used (create/edit/delete) and when he did the operation.

My question is how can I create two objects at the same time?

This is what's bothering me:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult DodajPreduzece()
{
     Preduzece preduzece = new Preduzece();
     IstorijaPromena istorijaPromena = new IstorijaPromena();

     return View(preduzece); //How can I pass two objects to POST, and how can I create them?
}
```

Sorry if this was already answered I just can't find it anywhere...

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make a type (class) that incorporates both variables, then return that container type? Does the end user need to see both values, or are do you only want the user to see one of the values and you're doing something in the background with the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are going about this wrong. I would look into database triggers as it seems like thats what you're looking to do.

The trigger can update a different table with the previous values after an insert, update or delete.

For example we have a table called applications and applications_jn(journal)

We then create a trigger that says after insert or update on table applications, insert the current values for that record into applications_jn.